# Operaciones en modelos Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

Si tengo el siguiente modelos con los siguientes métodos, donde `d_pendientes` queda con el resultado de la resta entre el valor introducido en el campo `dias_disponer` y `d_pendientes`, pero a la hora de ingresar los valores en el formulario, no sucede nada, como le hago por favor.

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class Disponibilidad(models.Model):
        solit_choices = (
            ('Disponer','Disponer'),
        )
        disponed_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        usuario = models.ForeignKey(LocalUsers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        null=True, 
        blank=True)
        disponsicion = models.CharField(max_length = 255, choices=solit_choices, 
        null=True, blank=False)
        fec = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        razon_2 = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
        periodo_i = models.DateField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=False)
        periodo_f = models.DateField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=False)
        dias_disponer = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False)
        horas_disponer = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False)

        def get_d_pendientes(self):
                return self.dias_diponer - self.d_pendientes
                d_pendientes = property(get_d_pendientes)

        def get_h_pendientes(self):
                return self.horas_disponer - self.h_pendientes
                h_pendientes = property(h_pendientes)
```

El archivo del formulario es el siguiente:

Archivo `forms.py`:

```
class SolitForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        """Formulario de solicitud"""

        model = Peticion

        fields = [

            'solicitudes_id',
            'petit',
            'razon',
            'periodo_init',
            'periodo_fin',
            'dias_adicion',
            'horas_adicion',    
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tienes un error de concepto, lo que quieres hacer se hace con javascript, solo después de guardar los datos es que podrás acceder a ese dato de la función, si quieres ver la resta en el momento de introducir tienes que usar si o si javascript, django solo te hace el calculo cuando mandas la información al servidor.

Saludos

Comment: Pero me puedes especificar la tecnologia, ajax? Es que no entiendo, estoy buscando por ajax, pero Ajax unifica todos los campos en una variable "data" : $formData, saludos cordiales y gracias por el comentario

Comment: Te explico con mis palabras, ajax hace un post o get al servidor asincronamente, es decir, como en un hilo de ejecución diferente, que no es necesario que se recargue la pagina para que le mandes información al servidor. esto se realiza con javascript, ahora para tu problema no es necesario ajax, puedes hacerlo con javascript, pero tienes que aprender a manipular el DOM o los elementos de la pagina.